# Memory leak with vertx SqlClient

Tags: java, postgresql, vert.x

I have an application that - in the end - grab independent sql queries from a non-blocking queue and execute them in a postgres database.

I had a memory issue due to the insert process bottlenecking and making the queries queue grows too big.

I tried the VertX postgressql client, to see if it could dequeue faster. As a matter of fact, it does greatly, but it seems I just moved the memory problem from one queue to another...

[MAT Suspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8XhU.png)

My code seems quite simple :

```
    @Override
    public void initialize() {
        conOptions = new PgConnectOptions().setHost(conf.getDbHost()).setDatabase(conf.getDbName())
                .setUser(conf.getDbUser()).setPassword(conf.getDbPassword());

        poolOptions = new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(5);
        client = PgPool.client(conOptions, poolOptions);
    }
    
        @Override
    public void executeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException {
        countIn.accumulate(1L);
        client.query(sql).execute().onComplete(ar -> {
            countOut.accumulate(1L);
            if (!ar.succeeded()) {
                LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass()).error(ar.cause().getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, something missing with vertx or jdbc driver ? or did I have unrealistic expectations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase throughput, you should increase the connection pool size beyond the default (5). Check with your DBA how many concurrent connections you can create.

Also, depending on your workload, you might benefit from [pipelining](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-pg-client/java/#_command_pipelining). It's not silver bullet, so try it in a testing environment and make measurements.

But at the end of the day, if you flood your database with updates, then yes, pending requests will sit in a queue somewhere. It's your responsibility to make sure you don't submit more concurrent requests to the client than the system is able to handle.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, I will just explain how I got rid of my problem : As you said : if I the db can't handle it, there will be a queue somewhere... 
So I had 2 solutions : 
1/ willingly slow down the process (make thread wait when the queue has reached a given size, depending on available memory).
2/ boost database performance.

Option 1 works well, but is a little erratic. 
Option 2 can be achieved easily in postgres : synchronous_commit=off is the key... In my case I have no problem handling the cons of an asynchronous commit.